# Python: How to order a list while using for loops and a file. (Homework)

Tags: python, file, list, for-loop

Basically I need the names of the students to be attributed to their respective grades in the order of the list.
So this is what I have so far:

```
def main():
```

Define myFile and open/read grades.txt file

```
myFile = open("grade.txt", "r")
```

Define the number of students and grade percentages
for assignments, quizzes and exams

```
numStudents = int(myFile.readline())
prctgs = myFile.readline().split()
students = ["Amy", "Jack", "Arron", "Zack", "Jen", "Jane"]
```

Create for loop to go through each of the students' scores

```
for i in range(numStudents):
```

Store each student's grades

```
stdntGrades = myFile.readline().split()
```

Calculate grade percentage

```
grade = 0
for j in range(len(prctgs)):
    grade = grade + float(prctgs[j]) * int(stdntGrades[j])
    print("Student #", i+1, ": ", " %.2f" % grade, sep="")

myFile.close()

main()
```

'students' is the list in question, I had also tried to directly
input the names into the file but that failed miserably

The 'grade.txt' file has the following in it:

```
6
.3 .1 .6
90 89 78
96 92 79
85 100 94
87 92 96
81 88 93
85 91 99
```

Note: This is my fifth program, so I am a complete beginner.

Comment: So what is your question specifically?  The more specific you can make your question, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: I'm confused. At first you read the file and show us that it contains names, while later on you show that the file only contains numbers, which is rather weird.

Comment: OH, nonono, the 'myFile' is just the name i assigned to the variable. It isn't the actual file, the list 'students' is what contains the names.
My question is how can I input the names along with the grade averages within the file? Because every way I tried has given me an error.
So I want it to return:
Amy: 82.70
Jack: 85.40
etc.

Comment: @user2074160 what tools do you have available to use?  Are you allowed to use builtins like `zip`?

Comment: Well according to my professor anything within python 3.x is allowed so long as we can explain what it does.
But I am not familiar with 'zip'.

Answer (score 0):

The students' names should be part of the data, not the code:

```
6
.3 .1 .6
Amy 90 89 78
Jack 96 92 79
Aaron 85 100 94
Zack 87 92 96
Jen 81 88 93
Jane 85 91 99
```

Then read them in along with the data:

```
line = file.readline().split()
student = line[0]
prctgs = line[1:]
```

Comment: I think that this is a homework assignment.  It seems to me like we're going toward `zip`...

Comment: The answer didn't seem to work :/ I have tried something like this and retried this just now and still nothing.
Also, yes this is homework, it is stated in the title. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume we have 2 strings ...

```
weights = "0.3 0.1 0.3"
grades =  "90   87  92"
```

You already know that you can split these up into lists:

```
weights.split() #['0.3', '0.1', '0.3]
grades.split() #['90', '87', '92']
```

Now you say to yourself -- "Wouldn't it be nice if I could get the matching numbers at the same time?"  Well, you can.  That's what `zip` is built for:

```
total = 0
for weight,grade in zip(weights.split(),grades.split()):
    total += float(weight)*float(grade)
```

This can even be shortened using `sum` if you'd like:

```
total = sum( float(w)*float(g) for w,g in zip(weights.split(),grades.split() )
```

So, this gives you one person's total.  Now, we can use the same concept when working with the file.  We want to "zip" the person's name with their grade information.  Here's how:

```
with open('grade.txt') as data: #fancy way of opening files...
    npeople = int(next(data)) #read first line, make an integer
    weights = [float(x) for x in next(data).split()] #get the weights as a list of floats
    people = ['jack','jill','mary','little miss muffet','kermit','animal']
    for person, grade_info in zip(people,data):
        grade = sum( w*float(g) for w,g in zip(weights,grade_info.split() )
        print person,grade
```

Another trick that I've used here is `next(fileobject)`.  That's just a fancy way of saying `fileobject.readline()`.  In fact, in python3.x, `fileobject.readline()` no longer exists ... Might as well get used to using `next` now :).

The 4 [builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) that I've used here are `zip`, `next`, `float` and `sum`.  `float` and `sum` are pretty obvious how they work so they don't take much work to explain.  `zip` and `next` are a little more tricky.  Read the linked docs until you understand them.  They're super useful.  I've also used [list-comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for building some lists.  They're super useful as well.  Definitely something you want in your python utility belt.

Comment: Hm, I'll see what I can cook up with this!